# Forgot Stack Exchange password and no access to email

Tags: support, android-app, stack-exchange

I've forgotten my Stack Exchange password and I no longer have access to my email.

But, I'm already logged in Stack Exchange app in my Android smartphone (that's where I'm asking from)

What can I do to gain access to my account and log in from my computer?

Answer (score 3):

If the app allows you to add another login credential, do that -- you can use Google or Facebook in addition to an email address.  I don't see a way to do that, but I'm not super-familiar with the app.

If the app doesn't allow you to add a credential, you'll need to contact SE for help.  That help might take the form of creating a new account and merging it into your existing one; SE usually allows merges if you can prove ownership of both accounts, and you *are* logged in to the current one.

If you no longer have access to the email address you used to create your account, it's a very good idea to add another credential anyway, or change your email address.

Comment: I didn't notice when I answered that this question is over two years old (and was recently bumped).  I hope Dake got back into his account by now.